# Does a plane passing througth the centroid of two points in euclidean 3D space must contain the two points?

Tags: geometry, centroid

Assume we have two points A and B in euclidean 3D space. The centroid of these two points is C. Now assume we define a plane P by means of the centroid C and an arbitrary normal vector n. Does the plane P must contain points A and B?

Comment: No. A can be "above" and B "below" the plane.

Comment: What do you mean by "centroid" of two points?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That answer the question definitely.